# How to fix duplicate entry for key primary when inserting into database?

Tags: java, android, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have an android app where the user inserts records in the table.  The app has worked fine for months.  For the past few days, I have been receiving the duplicate entry for primary error.  I'm not sure what the issue is.

I'm using GenerationType Sequence for my entity. Could it be that the sequence number is off?  And if so why did that happen?  I'm also adding to this table from another app, could that be the issue?

I've tried changing the way the record inserts but I still get the same error.  Maybe if I knew why this was suddenly happening I could figure out the code.

```
@Entity(name="bmwsales")
@Table(name="bmwsales")
public class Bmwsales implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@Column(name="id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="customerfirstname")
private String customerfirstname;

   ..................
```

Where the service is implemented:

```
@Override
public void addBmwvehicle(Bmwsales vehicle) {
    rolllogger.info("add bmw customer vehicle");
 bmwsalesRepository.save(vehicle);
}
```

Error:

```
Duplicate entry '35475' for key 'PRIMARY'
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper in logExceptions at line 131
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper in convert at line 110
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch in performExecution at line 128
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.BatchingBatch in doExecuteBatch at line 104
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.AbstractBatchImpl in execute at line 147
org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl in executeBatch at line 212
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue in executeActions at line 629
org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue in executeActions at line 474
```

I would like the record to be inserted as needed.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which DBMS are you using and what is the other application doing that inserts into the DB?

Comment: I'm using Amazon RDS Mysql.  I have a AWS Lambda running every night to insert data into this table. @Henry

Comment: MySQL does not have sequences. I don't know what hibernate is doing when you use `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`. In any case, you need to make sure that both programs use the same generation method for the primary key.

Comment: Ok so which GenerationType should I use with MySQL?  I have the primary key as auto-increment but I guess that doesn't matter?

Comment: It is better to use `GenerationType.IDENTITY`. Be careful with the existing data. Some migration may be necessary.

Comment: Ok thanks! So should I back up my table before making the change?  UGH...wish I knew this beforehand........

Comment: Having a backup is never wrong.

Comment: Ok great.  Thank you so much.  I'm going to change to identity but will have I delete my data before doing this and reload it?  What's the best way to go about this change?

Comment: I would try to just change to identity.

Comment: OK Thanks....will try now.